# JavaConfig: Replacing spring xml to java configuration

Tags: java, spring, configuration, aop

Please suggest me how to change xml configuration to Java Configuration. I want to remove xml file from classpath and want to use java configuration only .

```
xml config consisting of tx:advice ,aop:pointcut ,aop:advisor .
```

Some of the post saying we can not completely  remove the spring xml file for the above configuration . Please suggest .

Comment: No that's not true. you can get ride of xml's if you do it correctly. follow https://www.robinhowlett.com/blog/2013/02/13/spring-app-migration-from-xml-to-java-based-config/

Comment: Yes, in above hyperlink you may add package scan in xml file and add @Configuration for adding all your configurations.
Also you can add configuration class in web.xml and add package scan in your config class itself.

Comment: Could you please convert the XML tag tx:advice ,aop:pointcut ,aop:advisor into Java configuration. I have not found any substitute for the given XML tag.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that your question is considered inadequate as it lacks detail and focus, which is why it already received two close votes. Please be advised to learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is. Then edit your question and show your XML config, not just bullet points. SO is about code, not about abstract questions. What have you tried? What does work and what not?